# Command line tool to analyze a .app or .ipa file

Tags: ios, scripting

In a script I'm writing, I want a way to be able to analyze a .ipa or .app file to determine some of its internals, such as which SDK it was built with. Is there a command line tool that allows you to do this? If so, what other information can you get from it?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: https://github.com/apperian/iOS-checkIPA (it's a tool named iOS IPA Validator, originally by G. Gold, maintained by James Seibel)

It helped me.

This also looks interested: https://github.com/sjmulder/ipa

Comment: provide an excerpt of the external resources here!

Comment: What do you mean? The link already points to a bash script that i think the user wants.

Comment: link-only answers are not good as the external source might become inavailable in future, so the core information should be provided in your post...

Comment: I agree, but I don't see any other solution. I updated the answer with the name of the tool and the developer.